# how to reload data in tableview inside tableview controller cell correctly in swift 4?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, swift4

I have a table view(named B) inside one of the tableview controller(named A) cells and I have one button in tableView A cell(named add) and in that cell I have tableview B and tableview B has a button(named Delete) and textfield for each cells so I want when user push add button table view B reload and have a new row and when user push delete button table view B reload and remove that row for understanding better I have a video that you can see the link of that here 
https://ufile.io/5x6y1

in this video, you can see what will happen and what I want to do

and here is the codes for delete and add button in the main table view class (**remember the add button in the table view A cell (the main table view cell and the delete button is in the table view B cell (in each cell in table view B that is inside main table view (table view A) cell)**)

```
    var certificates = [String]()
    if self.pf.Licences.count != 0 {
               for i in 0...self.pf.Licences.count - 1 {
                    print(self.pf.Licences[i].title!)
                            self.certificates.append(self.pf.Licences[i].title!)
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }

 @IBAction func deleteCer(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("delete")
    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    certificates.remove(at: buttonRow)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 6)], with: .right)
    }
}

@IBAction func addingCertificate(_ sender: UIButton) {

    print("add")
    if certificates.count != 0 {
        if certificates[certificates.count - 1] != "" {
            certificates.append("")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 6)], with: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
           print(certificates)
           certificates.append("")
            print(certificates)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 6)], with: .bottom)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you do `for i in 0...self.pf.Licences.count - 1` you could simplify that to `for license in self.pf.Licences`

Comment: But when I use  license in self.pf.Licences what should I use instead of i in the self.certificates.append(self.pf.Licences[i].title!)

Comment: You’re not doing anything special with the loop counter other than using it as an index for retrieving data from the array. You don’t have any conditionals based on the index, that’s why you can just get rid of it and use the suggestion as it will just give you each license in your Licenses array.

Comment: I used an array because the licences  will get from Json and I want to append some data so I have main array named certificates and when user coming to this page certificates will equal to the licences array and then user can remove or append items

Comment: That has nothing to do with you just accessing each license’s title.

Comment: can you write codes here I will understand better

Answer (score 0):

In order for your additions and deletions to work you need to look into how these should be done on a UITableView at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview, under the section "Inserting, Deleting, and Moving Rows and Sections".

You will essentially need to use `insertRows(at:with:)` and `deleteRows(at:with:)` whilst making sure that your data source is updated.

If you have a controller of some sort for your UITableView B, you should probably be sending the insert and delete messages to that, not the parent UITableView A.

On a different note, where you use `certificates[certificates.count - 1]` you could just use `certificates.last`.